# How to keep only specific numbers of elements in a list based on columns used for sorting?

Tags: python, list, sorting

Okay so I have a list with following structure:

```
List1=[[a,b,c,data1,e],
[a,b,c,data2,e],
[a,b,c,data3,e],
[a,b,c,data1,e],
[a,b,c,data2,e],
[a,b,c,data3,e],
[a,b,c,data1,e],
[a,b,c,data1,e],
[a,b,c,data2,e],
[a,b,c,data3,e]]
```

Now I have sorted the list using:

```
List1.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[3])
```

Output generated is:

```
List1=[[a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data2,e],
    [a,b,c,data2,e],
    [a,b,c,data2,e],
    [a,b,c,data3,e],
    [a,b,c,data3,e],
    [a,b,c,data3,e]]
```

what I want to achieve is have only 2 elements for each distinct value of data i.e:

```
List1=[[a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data1,e],
    [a,b,c,data2,e],
    [a,b,c,data2,e],
    [a,b,c,data3,e],
    [a,b,c,data3,e]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
List1 = [["a", "b", "c", "data1", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data2", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data3", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data1", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data2", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data3", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data1", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data1", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data2", "e"],
         ["a", "b", "c", "data3", "e"]]
def group(l,n,key=lambda e:e):
    l = sorted(l,key=key)
    out = l[:n]
    for line in l:
        if key(line) != key(out[-n]):
            out.append(line)
    return out


print(group(List1,2,lambda e:e[3]))
```

prints:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'data1', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'data1', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'data2', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'data2', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'data3', 'e'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'data3', 'e']]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correct but try this:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
data1 = 4
data2 = 5
data3 = 6
e = 7

list_1 = [[a, b, c, data1, e],
          [a, b, c, data1, e],
          [a, b, c, data1, e],
          [a, b, c, data1, e],
          [a, b, c, data2, e],
          [a, b, c, data2, e],
          [a, b, c, data2, e],
          [a, b, c, data3, e],
          [a, b, c, data3, e],
          [a, b, c, data3, e]]

list_1.sort(key=lambda elem: elem[3])
for x, _list in enumerate(list_1):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        del list_1[x]

print(list_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, chain
num_to_keep = 2
d = [list(islice(group, num_to_keep)) 
     for key, group in groupby(List1, lambda x: x[3])]
list(chain(*d))
```

The same code expanded with explanations

```
# Group by data
grouped = groupby(List1, lambda x: x[3])
# Keep only the first 2 of each distinct value of data
num_to_keep = 2
d = [list(islice(group, num_to_keep)) for key, group in grouped]
# Flatten list
list(chain(*d))
```

Note that the code is keeping the first 2 rows with the same value of "data". However, the other entries could have different values. You did not specify how you would pick 2 rows from among them. Also, List1 should be sorted base on the entry "data" which you are using to group the rows before running the code.